# rubygems update broke ruby on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I was having some trouble running some Ruby scripts. While trying to get these scripts to run I tried lots of different things as well as updating rubygems as I thought this may be the problem. Since then I can't get any Ruby scripts to run.

I think that if I can revert rubygems back to it's original version I may be able to run Ruby scripts again, but I don't know how.

```
    $ gem environment
  RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/ryan/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/

    $ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-darwin10]

    $ which -a ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

    $ which -a gem
/usr/bin/gem
/usr/local/bin/gem
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Ryan

```
$ ruby spidr_start_at.rb 
spidr_start_at.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from spidr_start_at.rb:1

$ cat spidr_start_at.rb 
require 'rubygems'
require 'uri'
require 'spidr'

url = 'http://www.ethicalhack3r.co.uk'

puts "Spidr.start_at()"
puts

Spidr.start_at(url, :depth => 1) do |spider|

 spider.every_page do |page|
  puts page.url.to_s
 end

end
```

Comment: If you could provide us with the symptoms of the problem (i.e. an actual error that indicates you can't run any Ruby scripts) we can help you solve it much easier.

Comment: Your right, I should have put that in originally. I have amended my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have multiple versions of ruby(and gem) installed. It is advised to use `rvm` when maintaining multiple ruby versions. Or clean up your wrong/old/unneeded installations.

Comment: Do you think the best way to solve would be to remove all and start a fresh? If so, what's the best way or removing all ruby and rubygems? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any automated ways to remove those. Doing it by hand is probably the best way. Your original post has a lot of directories, that is probably a good start. Once one, read on `rvm` in case you want to have ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 installed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

For downgrading Rubygems, you can do the following:

```
sudo gem update --system VERSION
```

You obviously have to put a real version there.

Comment: I get the following error: `$ sudo gem update --system 1.3.4
Updating RubyGems
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    No gem names are allowed with the --system option
`